# unable to update a certificate with Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings

Tags: azure, office365, saml, idp

adding a certificate with Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings
The cert for my IDP expires in a week, and I am trying to add a next signing cert without having to switch to managed and back to federated. I'm trying to use the command below, but it's giving me an error message. At first I thought it was an issue with the way I entered the cert into powershell, so I setup a test Azure environment, and setup federation and added the next signing certificate during setup using Set-MsolDomainAuthentication. Everything looked good. So I toggled Federation off then back on, this time not adding the next signing cert. I then tried to enter the command below and it still fails in my test environment.

PS C:\Users\administrator.CLI> Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName $domainName -NextSigningCertificate $NextCertificate

Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings : Invalid value for parameter. Parameter Name: PreferredProtocol.

At line:1 char:1

- Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings -DomainName $domainName -SigningCert ...
- 
- CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings], MicrosoftOnlineException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PropertyValidationException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.SetDomainFederationSettings

Any ideas?

Comment: Server Fault may be a good place to ask this question. https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had to add `-PreferredAuthenticationProtocol "SAMLP"` as a parameter to `Set-MsolDomainFederationSettings`.

Not very intuitive, seeing as "PreferredProtocol" doesn't exist anywhere in Microsoft's documentation.